# Installing MySQL on a VPS server and connecting from other servers

Tags: mysql, vps

I have few VPS servers and few Cloud servers across the globe (West US, South Us, Europe, China) and users are redirected to the nearest server with DNS IP Geolocation. My servers currently serve static content but I am changing my app so I am in need of a database, particularly MySQL.

At first I was going to use Amazon RDS but I found out that installing my own MySQL on a VPS it will end up cheaper ($72 dollars for a small instance VS $40 dollars of a Linode 1024)

So I bought a linode VPS in London and I installed MySQL and Phpmyadmin onto my VPS and within Phpmyadmin my user is root@localhost thus I cannot connect to my database from my other servers.

```
Server version: 5.0.51a-24+lenny5
Protocol version: 10
Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
User: root@localhost
```

What I'm I missing here? How can I make this MySQL database accessed globaly?

All my cloud/VPS servers are Debian 5.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to [enable remote connections](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html).

Most specifically, you'll have to add a MySQL user with the appropriate permissions for your database for each IP that needs to connect.

The linked article shows all the steps you'll have to perform.

Comment: Thank you. Is this the way to go you think in my situation or would you suggest any other way of using database?

Comment: It may be the easiest way to introduce a database in a distributed situation like this, but you should be aware that it will introduce some (maybe a lot) lag when the other servers have to call off to the database, since it will have to go over the Internet.

Comment: that is my question. How do people actually deal with this stuff when they have multiple servers across the globe and 1 database?