# MySQL database not allowing outside connections?

Tags: c#, mysql

Sorry if this was posted in the wrong area but is there away to get my C# program to connect to my database? It's not allowing outside connections.
Can you make your database open to connections? It was installed via Ubuntu 15.04 // PHPMyAdmin

```
string myConnection = "datasource=my_host;port=3306;username=my_user;password=my_pass";
MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(myConnection);
```

I'm trying to create a game launcher and making it check for a password that is hashed in the database.

Comment: You probably need to modify the permissions on the database itself, locally through the MySql command prompt or the MySql workbench. It probably doesn't have anything to do with your connection string.

Comment: Where is the database located? If it is on a different machine, you'll need to account for that as well.

Comment: @Ben, it is located on a VPS that I've purchased. and Ron Beyer, where can I find those permissions?

Comment: Depends, are you using the workbench or some other tool like PHPmyAdmin? Sorry, I see it now, I will check.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9609053/3073006) may have some valuable info for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment out the bind-address in your my.cnf/my.ini (depending on OS). Then restart mysql so that the changes to the my.cnf/my.ini file will take affect. You can read more here at [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-allow-remote-mysql-database-connection). Now, anyone will be able to connect to your Mysql database remotely as long as they have proper user credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your phpMyAdmin website and select the "Users" tab at the top.

Edit Privileges for the user that you want to be able to access the database remotely.

Scroll to the bottom, make sure the host setting is set to any host and the textbox says %.

Hit "Go" at the bottom to save your changes.

Comment: Okay I did that, I'm still getting a cannot connect error?

Comment: Are all the permissions at the top of that page checked?

Comment: Yes. I still cannot connect. Do I need to use an IP or a domain which is pointing to the IP?

Comment: You may want to try it with the IP, it would mean that some other system settings aren't quite right.